# Is there a way to delay a video feed from a cell phone camera in Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I am making a project where you are supposed to be able to change the delay with which the feed from the cell phone camera is shown, so that people can see how their brains handle the delay/latency. I have managed to show the camera feed on a canvas that follows the camera around and fills the whole view of the Google Cardboard, but I am wondering how I could delay this video feed. Perhaps by using an image array of some sort?

I have tried searching for sollutions online, but I have come up short of an answer. I have tried a texture2D array, but the performance was really bad (I tried a modified version of [this](https://medium.com/google-developers/real-time-image-capture-in-unity-458de1364a4c)).

```
    private bool camAvailable;
    private WebCamTexture backCam;
    private Texture defaultBackground;

    public RawImage background;
    public AspectRatioFitter fit;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        defaultBackground = background.texture;
        WebCamDevice[] devices = WebCamTexture.devices;

        if (devices.Length == 0 )
        {
            Debug.Log("No camera detected");
            camAvailable = false;
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < devices.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!devices[i].isFrontFacing)
            {
                backCam = new WebCamTexture(devices[i].name, Screen.width, Screen.height); // Used to find the correct camera
            }
        }

        if (backCam == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Unable to find back camera");
            return;
        }

        backCam.Play();
        background.texture = backCam;

        camAvailable = true;
    } //Tell me if this is not enough code, I don't really have a lot of experience in Unity, so I am unsure of how much is required for a minimal reproducible example
```

Should I use some sort of frame buffer or image/texture array for delaying the video? (Start "recording", wait a specified amount of time, start playing the "video" on the screen)

Thanks in advance!